# Powershell parallel and serial operations

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am using the PowerCLI module for VMWare and I need to shut off 4 sets of computers (so group 1 off, confirm they are all off, group 2 off, confirm they are all off, etc...)  It is important that I confirm one set of servers is down before moving on to the next set.

To save time I would like to send a VMGuest-Shutdown to all servers in the first group, then go back and verify the power status one at a time before moving on to the next group of servers.

Here's what I have, but it doesn't seem to work.  I would assume I could do this in a subroutine within the first command set, but I am a little green to know where to go with it.

```
$gssservers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "App"} | Foreach-Object {
    Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_.Name -Confirm:$false
    }
$gssservers.reset()
$gssservers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "App"} | Foreach-Object {
    $counter = 0
    while((Get-VM $_.Name).PowerState -ne "PoweredOff" -and $counter -lt $maxcounter){
        sleep 5
        $counter += $maxcounter
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding $maxcounter to $counter in the polling loop will cause the loop to only be executed once. (Second time through the loop $counter will equal $maxcounter).

I think you want `$counter++` instead.

I don't know anything about the PowerCLI VMware module, but if `$gsservers.reset()` causes the list of servers contained within $gsservers to change, then that would introduce another bug (because the second loop wouldn't be checking the set of servers you sent shutdowns to in the first loop).

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the Cmd executes synchronoulsy 'Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_.Name -Confirm:$false' ?

Then i think you should use PowerShell back ground jobs to run ur Cmdlets in background. this way you can simply invoke the shut down cmd on all vms in back ground, without waiting for the shut down cmdlet to finish.

Here are some useful links: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878288(v=vs.85).aspx

Regards.